# Meaning behind multiplication of matrix and its transpose

Tags: matrices

When you multiply a matrix $M$ by its transpose, what exactly does this product represent? What does each entry represent?

I see that a lot of these examples, when a [document-term matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix) (DTM) is created and then this DTM is multiplied by its transpose and they call it the term-term matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If the rows of $M$ are $m_1, m_2,\ldots, m_n$, then the $i,j^\textrm{th}$ entry of $MM^T$ is $m_i\cdot m_j$, the dot product.

Comment: looks like we are reducing a dimension when we do this kind of dot product. My question is what is the value m i ⋅m j  actually represent?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Answer (score 0):

The matrix product $X=A^t*A$ is essential in several contexts. If you are only looking for an interpretation of its elements then the most obvious is that $X$ contains the cross-correlations of the columns of $A$. $X$ is always square, symmetric, and positive semi-definite (all eigenvalues are >= 0). The diagonal values contain the sum of the squares of each column, and a sum can never be zero unless a column of $A$ contains all zeros. The off-diagonal values of $X$ are the cross-correlations between columns. For example, with
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4\\
2 & 5\\
3 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
14 & 32\\
32 & 77\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
.
The eigenvalues of $X$ are both greater than zero because the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. On the other hand, with
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 4\\
3 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
14 & 28\\
28 & 56\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

which is singular because the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent (eigenvalues 0 and 70). $X$ always has the same rank as $A$ regardless of the number of rows and columns in A. The off-diagonal elements in $X$ can be zero if two columns in $A$ are orthogonal. As an example, with 
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\
2 & 0\\
3 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
14 & 0\\
0 & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
.
If you have more than a passing interest in the subject, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition. It is well worth the effort.